# Есть ли возможность запустить данный код в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, парсер, браузер

Здрасте, а есть ли возможность провернуть такое в браузере

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
var day, temp, weather, when;

const parse = async () => {
  const getHTML = async (url) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);

    return cheerio.load(data);
  };

  const $ = await getHTML("https://ru-meteo.ru/chelyabinsk");
  when = $("div.dt")
    .first()
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
      return this.type === "text";
    })
    .text();
  day = $("div.dt big").eq(0).text();
  temp = $("div.wtr big").eq(0).text();
  weather = $("div.wtr p").eq(0).text();
};

parse();
```

Код парсит с сайта погоду, полученные данные я хочу вывести на html страницу, но если данный скрипт подключать к html, то выводит ошибку `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`, как быть? Или это возможно только в node.js? На чистом js такое не получится?

Comment: Браузер в принципе не позволит читать страницы сторонних сайтов, поэтому даже пытаться переделать скрипт нет смысла

Comment: Обидно, ну лан :0

Comment: 1 каждый второй сервис погоды спокойно отдает данные через апи и парсить его html вёрстку попросту не зачем(только если хочется по фану размятся в написании парсера). 2 если тех данных которые необходимы, в апи нету и как ни крути надо парсить - можно создать свою html страницу подцепить на ней все что душе угодно включая ноду, а после добавить на ней же фрейм `<iframe src='ru-meteo.ru/'>` и жанглировать содержимым как душе угодно(но это разумеется при условии, что нужный сайт не лочит загрузку во фреймах). 3 написать браузерное расширение... 4 как все нормальные люди писать парсер на бэке

Comment: @puffleeck даже если сайт не лочит загрузку во фреймах, браузер всё равно не позволит получить доступ к содержимому фрейма

Comment: Если вы очень хотите, можете попробовать эти библиотеки подключить через [CDN](https://github.com/axios/axios#cdn) Вдруг у вас получится осуществить задуманное ) Еще вариант - использовать сборщик js, например webpack, для сборки общего бандла js

Comment: @SwaD всё это никак не поможет получить доступ к html-коду стороннего сайта

Answer (score 0):

Такая возможность есть. Только код придётся писать совсем иначе. Подключение библиотек будет не через require, а через тэг script, также будут проблемы с синхронным выполнением кода, так как браузер сам будет определять какой файл быстрее подключить. Вот пример, который выведет ваш город с которого вы откроете страницу через 5 секунд.

И да, с вашим сайтом это скорее всего не сработает. Политика браузера CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) такова, что не позволит считывать данные с HTTPS, если сам владелец хоста это не разрешит в настройках своего сервера. Поэтому в моём предоставленном примере используется протокол HTTP.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      setTimeout(async () => {
        const data = await axios.get('http://ip-api.com/json');
        document.body.innerHTML = data.data.city;
      }, 5000);
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.1/axios.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: С сайтом ru-meteo.ru этот код не сработает

Comment: Действительно, Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://ru-meteo.ru. Но спасибо за ответ!)